# How to show the information from the link without leaving the site? PHP

Tags: php

I got the site fully working and returning the information from the rss feed since the it return with website link how can i display the information from the link instead of redirect the user back to the original site?

```
<?php

    $query = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=Select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fnestor.sunderland.ac.uk%2F~bf71wx%2FphpTest%2Fjquery.mobile-1.0.1%2520-%2520%25E8%25A4%2587%25E8%25A3%25BD%2Fjquery.mobile-1.0.1%2Fdemos%2Fdocs%2Frss%2FNews.xml%22%20&diagnostics=true';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($query);
    //var_dump($xml);

    echo '<h2>World of Tank News</h2>';

    //iterate over query result set
    $results = $xml->results;
    foreach ($results->item as $r){
        echo $r->title . "<br />";
        echo "<a href=\"" . $r->link . "\">" . $r->link . "</a><br /><br />";
        echo 'Publish Date - ';

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use curl to read the info from link and publish it e.g.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

no need. you can add this code in your prog e.g.

```
<?php

$query = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=Select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fnestor.sunderland.ac.uk%2F~bf71wx%2FphpTest%2Fjquery.mobile-1.0.1%2520-%2520%25E8%25A4%2587%25E8%25A3%25BD%2Fjquery.mobile-1.0.1%2Fdemos%2Fdocs%2Frss%2FNews.xml%22%20&diagnostics=true';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($query);
//var_dump($xml);

echo '<h2>World of Tank News</h2>';

//iterate over query result set
$results = $xml->results;
foreach ($results->item as $r){
echo $r->title . "<br />";
$ch = curl_init();

$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$r->link);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
//        echo "<a href=\"" . $r->link . "\">" . $r->link . "</a><br /><br />";
//        echo 'Publish Date - ';

}

?>
```

Comment: Would that require me to create a new page in-order to achieve that ?:)

Comment: I will give this a try and then reply here for the result thanks for the time satya

Comment: appreciate it, do let me know how it goes

Comment: i got an error show 
Undefined variable: file in /home/bf71wx/public_html/phpTest/jquery.mobile-1.0.1 - 複製/jquery.mobile-1.0.1/demos/docs/about/news.php on line 40 Notice: Use of undefined constant link - assumed 'link' in /home/bf71wx/public_html/phpTest/jquery.mobile-1.0.1 - 複製/jquery.mobile-1.0.1/demos/docs/about/news.php on line 42 Fan Art Spotlight #17

Comment: there is a typo  $r>link should be  $r->link in the line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $r>link); modify and try

Comment: the output look more tidier but it still have the error on line 40 with undefined variable

Undefined variable: file in /home/bf71wx/public_html/phpTest/jquery.mobile-1.0.1 - 複製/jquery.mobile-1.0.1/demos/docs/about/news.php on line 40
line 40 contain `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);`

Comment: same error regarding undefined variable , its show that $timeout is not using in anywhere

Comment: it work this time without any error however it didnt return any link it only return the description

Comment: uncomment the last 2 lines and you should see the links